# Query efficiency (multiple selects)

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have two tables - one called `customer_records` and another called `customer_actions`.

`customer_records` has the following schema:

```
CustomerID (auto increment, primary key)
CustomerName
...etc...
```

`customer_actions` has the following schema:

```
ActionID (auto increment, primary key)
CustomerID (relates to customer_records)
ActionType
ActionTime (UNIX time stamp that the entry was made)
Note (TEXT type)
```

Every time a user carries out an action on a customer record, an entry is made in `customer_actions`, and the user is given the opportunity to enter a note. `ActionType` can be one of a few values (like 'designatory update' or 'added case info' - can only be one of a list of options).

What I want to be able to do is display a list of records from `customer_records` where the last `ActionType` was a certain value.

So far, I've searched the net/SO and come up with this monster:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT * FROM `customer_actions` ORDER BY `EntryID` DESC
    ) list1 GROUP BY `CustomerID`
) list2 WHERE `ActionType`='whatever' LIMIT 0,30
```

Which is great - it lists each customer ID and their last action. But the query is *extremely* slow on occasions (note: there are nearly 20,000 records in `customer_records`). Can anyone offer any tips on how I can sort this monster of a query out or adjust my table to give faster results? I'm using MySQL. Any help is really appreciated, thanks.

Edit: To be clear, I need to see a list of customers who's last action was 'whatever'.

Comment: Does this mean that if a customer's last action (by ActionDate) is *not* 'whatever' then that customer should not be listed?  And for the customers that *Are* listed, do you just want the customer, or also their last action, or also all of their actions?

Comment: @Dems If the latest `ActionType` for a customer is not 'whatever' then they should not be displayed. For those that have the latest `ActionType` of 'whatever' I'll need their information from `customer_records` - but this doesn't need to be covered all in one query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To filter customers by their last action, you could use a correlated sub-query...

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  customer_records
INNER JOIN
  customer_actions
    ON  customer_actions.CustomerID = customer_records.CustomerID
    AND customer_actions.ActionDate = (
           SELECT
             MAX(ActionDate)
           FROM
             customer_actions  AS lookup
           WHERE
             CustomerID = customer_records.CustomerID
        )
WHERE
  customer_actions.ActionType = 'Whatever'
```

You may find it more efficient to avoid the correlated sub-query as follows...

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  customer_records
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT CustomerID, MAX(ActionDate) AS ActionDate FROM customer_actions GROUP BY CustomerID) AS last_action
    ON customer_records.CustomerID = last_action.CustomerID
INNER JOIN
  customer_actions 
    ON  customer_actions.CustomerID = last_action.CustomerID
    AND customer_actions.ActionDate = last_action.ActionDate
WHERE
  customer_actions.ActionType = 'Whatever'
```

Comment: Thanks - the first query returned the results expected (fantastic!) but took *445 seconds* to do so :-| ! The second query returned an empty set.

Comment: @JonnyKeogh - Two typos in there, now corrected.  *[Do you have a covering index on customer_actions(CustomerID, ActionDate)?]*

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I understand the requirements but it looks to me like a JOIN would be enough for that.

```
SELECT  cr.CustomerID, cr.CustomerName, ...
FROM    customer_records cr
        INNER JOIN customer_actions ca ON ca.CustomerID = cr.CustomerID
WHERE   `ActionType` = 'whatever'
ORDER BY
        ca.EntryID
```

*Note that 20.000 records should not pose a performance problem*

Comment: In addition to the above if you're re-factoring this then I strongly suggest moving away from * and using only the column names that you require directly (selecting * is a big performance hit)

Comment: This query selects all customers who have had 'whatever' performed on their record at some point, but I need to see customers where the last action performed on their record was 'whatever'. Sorry, I wasn't quite clear in my original post.

Answer (score 2):

Please note that I've adapted Lieven's answer (I made a separate post as this was too long for a comment). Any credit for the solution itself goes to him, I'm just trying to show you some key points for improving performance.

If speed is a concern then the following should give you some suggestions for improving it:

```
select top 100 -- Change as required
        cr.CustomerID ,
        cr.CustomerName,
        cr.MoreDetail1,
        cr.Etc
from    customer_records cr
        inner join customer_actions ca 
            on ca.CustomerID = cr.CustomerID
where   ca.ActionType = 'x'
order by cr.CustomerID
```

A few notes:

- In some cases I find left outer joins to be faster then inner joins - It would be worth measuring performance for both for this query
- Avoid returning * wherever possible
- You don't have to reference 'cr.x' in the initial select but it's a good habit to get into for when you start working on large queries that can have multiple joins in them (this will make a lot of sense once you start doing this
- When using joins *always* join on a primary key

Comment: `TOP 100` should by `Limit 100`, but I'd guess the OP could work that out :)  But, for *always* joining on a Primary Key?  I don't actually agree here.  Should the `actions` table have a surrogate primary key, the functionality required by the OP will still require joining on fields not in the Primary Key.  What I would say is that as MySQL makes the Primary Key the Clustered Index, there are real benefits in doing so, but that if your logic means that you can't, ensure that you have an appropriate index.

Comment: Very valid points - will put more thought into this now. Thank-you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm missing something but what's wrong with a simple join and a where clause?

```
Select ActionType, ActionTime, Note
FROM Customer_Records CR
INNER JOIN customer_Actions CA 
  ON CR.CustomerID = CA.CustomerID
Where ActionType = 'added case info'
```

Comment: OP wants a list of customers where their last entry in the Action table is a specific action.  The "their last entry in the action table" is the part that is missing here.  *[But I did have to check with a comment to be certain.]*

Comment: Ah, yes I re-read the OP. "What I want to be able to do is display a list of records from customer_records where the last ActionType was a certain value."  this implied my response:  what I missed was later "  it lists each customer ID and their last action"